# How to return status 301 on port 80 without webserver

Tags: 16.04, server, webserver

Is there any way to implement HTTP redirect on port 80 if there's no web servers installed?

I want to protect my server from random access and redirect whoever hits port 80 or 443 there to the main websites. Right now it is setup to drop connection attempts on both ports.

I know, I could've created simple app that will listen port 80 and return http header with 301 status, but I'm curious if that's can be done kinda native?

Comment: the proper way is what you're doing - firewall off the port and letting the connections drop.  you can't serve a 301 redirect without some type of web server at play to issue the return, and because you don't want to do that you have already locked yourself out from any viable options.  Thereby leaving firewalling off the ports and dropping the traffic your only viable option (that you are already doing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use netcat as a very simple web server:

```
yes | xargs -i printf 'HTTP/1.0 301 Moved Permanently\nLocation: http://example.com\n\n' | sudo nc -k -l 80
```

Comment: fantastic! how could I forget about netcat??? exactly the answer I was looking for! thank you!

Comment: my 5 cents to this answer, it won't hurt to add 'Connection: close' to the headers and that's the right netcat: nc -l -p 80

Comment: @AlexD The `-p` is optional here. Without the `-k` netcat will not stay listening after the first connection is completed.  Closing the connection is the default in HTTP 1.0. If you want to use 'Connection: close' for some reason you need to replace 'HTTP/1.0' with 'HTTP/1.1',

Comment: that's correct. HTTP 1.1 would be required. I was playing with different port number to test it...and it didn't want to work without -p....anyway, problem is solved! Appreciate your help!

Comment: another option to that approach is to just force redirect any traffic on port 80 to the weserver IP: `iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination x.x.x.x:80` and `iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -j MASQUERADE` the plus here is that you can correctly handle port 443 like this without having actual https engine running